# Requirements for developing applications on windows

Tags: .net, windows

I am planning on to develop a application for windows. It is basically a phone manager for android phones. It communicates through the blue tooth with the phone to backup data and contacts. I have fair experience in .net and android programming. My only concern here is regarding the licensing issues when it come developing for windows OS.

My questions are

Is it advisable to develop using a cracked Visual studio from internet or should i purchase one before i start developing?

Is there any way Microsoft will be able to identify that it was developed on a cracked version?

Comment: It is generally advisable to remain in compliance with the [law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention_for_the_Protection_of_Literary_and_Artistic_Works). Proving this is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Pro tip: Don't discuss your use of pirated software online in public forums. Always a dead give-away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do yourself a favor. Go download Visual Studio 2010 Express (for free to learn) and develop your application. If you start selling it, buy yourself a copy of Visual Studio 2010 Professional and avoid any complications or worries.

I don't know what Microsoft's capabilities are regarding Visual Studio piracy, but I don't think you would get any sympathy on these forums if you were ever caught.

Comment: Thanks for the info regarding the free to learn, dave. Now i can start developing my application without having to invest 800$ initially. I am planning to launch only a free version of my application. So i was worried having to invest a lot of money in an app that finally goes for free.